# Running a Ruby website on localhost

Tags: ruby, webserver, localhost

After looking at other similar posts, I still need help.

My friend sent me a 1.3gb .zip file with a bunch of folders and scripts.  He says it's using Ruby.  I am completely clueless about Ruby, I know Java and HTML though.  How can I run this on my computer to test out the website?

[image]

Comment: Ask your friend! We don't know what's in your ZIP...

Comment: I have no idea sagar.  I added a picture AnoE

Comment: This is not the place to ask questions like these. Anyway, this is a rails project. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html take a look at this.

Comment: @avellable if you has submitted that as an answer, I would've accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

These are the general steps used to run a Ruby on Rails web site on localhost.  These are the things you will usually do, but may not be everything needed.  Whether or not the site will work on your box will depend upon its external dependencies and upon your operating system.

This is not meant to be a how-to: Everything I mention here, you'll have to research how to do.  This is meant to be a general cook-book to get your started.  Your particular web site may have steps not mentioned here.

- If you are running a different OS than the web site was written for, spin up a Virtual Machine with the web site's OS and use that.
- Install the version of Ruby that the web site requires.  You should be able to successfully execute the commands `ruby --version` and `gem list`.
- Run `bundle install` in order to install required Ruby gems.
- Install whatever database engine the site requires.
- Configure config/database.yml to point to the database.
- Run `rake db:setup` to create the database.
- Run `rails s` to start the project.
- Send your browser to http://localhost:3000